# Why this multi-threaded code is executed 5x more than it should?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I don't understand why this simple python example is executed 5x time more than it should :/ I looked at the code for 2h, searched on Google ect... I really don't see the problem here. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import urllib2
import socket
import Queue
import threading

socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
verbose = True

hosts = ['game1', 'game2', 'game3', 'game4', 'game5', 'game6']

queue = Queue.Queue()

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            host = self.queue.get()
            url = 'http://{0}.server.com'.format(host)
            f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            print f.read(1024)
            self.queue.task_done()


def main():

    for i in range(5):
        t = ThreadUrl(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

        for host in hosts:
            queue.put(host)

    queue.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Can you include the output you are getting which is leading you to believe it's misbehaving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because for each and every thread, you're putting all your hosts into the queue.

Comment: This was my interpretation of the cause....

Comment: Sorry I got the problem, the indentation of the queue.put(host) was wrong :/ Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pragmateek Well there is a timer to accept an answer, something like 10min :)

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know that, there is timers everywhere on SO ;)